# Auto Generated (Create a function which will return 12 digit incremental number Format MM-YY-00001, it should reset every month)

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite, sql-server-2008

Auto Generated (Create a function which will return 12 digit incremental number Format MM-YY-00001, it should reset every month)

How do I generate this in MicrosoftSQL?

Comment: Can you please explain how you would want this to increment? I assume that you're trying to insert this value into a table, though you would want the MM-yy prepended to the row number per month. Please correct me if this is not the case.

Comment: Do you want this number to be generated when the record is created, and stored in the table or are you allocating it later as part of some reporting process? Ie, is it a static, saved value in a table or a generated report value?

Answer (score 0):

CREATE FUNCTION Ref_no() 
RETURNS CHAR(20) 
AS 
BEGIN 
    DECLARE @reff_no CHAR(20)
    DECLARE @result CHAR(20)

--SET @reff_no = (SELECT MAX(refno) FROM jobOffer WHERE refno LIKE CONCAT( MONTH(getDate()), '-', SUBSTRING(YEAR(getDate()),3,2), '-%'))
   SET @reff_no = (SELECT MAX(refno) FROM jobOffer)

```
IF @reff_no is null 
    SET @result = CONCAT( RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, MONTH(getDate())),2), '-', SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar,YEAR(getDate())),3,2), '-', '000001')
ELSE
    BEGIN
        DECLARE @reff_month CHAR(20)
        SET @reff_month =  CONVERT(VARCHAR, LEFT(@reff_no,2));
        Declare @month CHAR(20)
        SET @month =  RIGHT('00'+CONVERT(VARCHAR, MONTH(getDate())),2);

        DECLARE @reff_year CHAR(20)
        SET @reff_year =  SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @reff_no),4,2);
        Declare @year CHAR(20)
        SET @year =  SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar,YEAR(getDate())),3,2);

            If @reff_year = @year AND @reff_month = @month
                BEGIN
                    DECLARE @no INT
                    SET @no = CONVERT(int,substring(@reff_no,7,6)) +1
                    DECLARE @s CHAR(20)
                    SET @s = RIGHT('000000' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),@no),6)
                    SET @result = CONCAT(RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, MONTH(getDate())),2), '-', SUBSTRING(CONVERT(varchar,YEAR(getDate())),3,2), '-',@s)
                END

            ELSE 
                    SET @result = CONCAT(RIGHT('00'+ CONVERT(VARCHAR, MONTH(getDate())),2), '-', SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR,YEAR(getDate())),3,2), '-', '000001')

    END
```

RETURN @result

END